# Bootstrap Date Picker End/Start Date Limit with Date Range

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using the [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and I have 2 `input` fields  (start date and end date) that use the date range option (`inputs:`) which works really well. I am trying to get the start field to require picking a date past today's date (so only a date today or a date in the past).

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
  $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    inputs: $('.date-control'),
    todayBtn: true,
    todayHighlight: true
  });
```

Here are the form fields:

```
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="date-start"><span class="text-danger">*</span>Project Start Date</label>
      <div class="input-group input-daterange">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">Started</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control date-control start-daterange" name="date-start" id="date-start" value="" required="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Project Start Date is required.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="date-end"><span class="text-danger">*</span>Project End Date</label>
      <div class="input-group input-daterange end-daterange">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">Finished</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control date-control" name="date-end" id="date-end" value="" required="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Project End Date is required.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have already tried to use `endDate: "0d";` to limit the start date field but if I do this it will also limit the end date field because they are being associated with the `inputs: $('.date-control')`. I [saw in the documents](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#enddate) that I could use `<input type="text" class="form-control" data-date-end-date="0d">` but this does not work either, maybe because I am using the `inputs` option?

So my question is there an easy way to keep using the date range option and be able to limit the start date field to select today date and any date in the past?

I have viewed these other semi-related SO questions [how to restrict bootstrap date picker from future date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964218/how-to-restrict-bootstrap-date-picker-from-future-date) and [How to have a dynamic maximum end date in Bootstrap Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922906/how-to-have-a-dynamic-maximum-end-date-in-bootstrap-date-picker). Also I am using the latest version of bootstrap datepicker (v1.8).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **inputs** option and the **data-date-end-date** attribute don't work well together. But there's a workaround and you'll get the same result. You can use the same class for both inputs and you can create the datepickers using that class. Besides that, you're gonna use the **data-date-end-date** attribute just in the start input, like this:

The Jquery code:

```
$('.date-control').datepicker({
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
  todayBtn: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

The form fields:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label for="date-start"><span class="text-danger">*</span>Project Start Date</label>
  <div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Started</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-control start-daterange" name="date-start" id="date-start" required="" data-date-end-date="0d">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Project Start Date is required.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label for="date-end"><span class="text-danger">*</span>Project End Date</label>
  <div class="input-group input-daterange end-daterange">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Finished</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-control" name="date-end" id="date-end" required="">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Project End Date is required.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ps: I've removed the value attribute from both inputs just to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks for responding. This works but it removes the association between the 2 fields which I need to keep intact which is why I am using `inputs: $('.date-control')`